# How to implement advanced routing in perl dancer for RESTful webservices?

Tags: perl, web-services, rest, dancer

I would like to implement a RESTful webservice backend using perl dancer and want to understand whether (eventually how) I can implement a rest-enpoint like this:

```
get qr{/this/:IS/one/:PATH/with/:MANY/variables/:ONEMORE} => sub() {

  # Does perl dancer support this?
  # How to implement this and get the variables?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why, but using `qr{...}` didn't work, but this format works fine:

```
get '/this/:IS/one/:PATH/with/:MANY/variables/:ONEMORE' => sub() {
  info("Variable IS = " . params->{IS});

}
```